# Adding custom font to SpriteKit with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, custom-font

I cannot seem to add my custom font. I have dragged it into my project and added it as a target to my project.

Code creating a label as follows:

```
// Create Unlock Text
func createUnlockText() {
    unlockText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "04b_19")
    unlockText.name = "unlockText"
    unlockText.text = "Goal: \(goalScore)"
    unlockText.fontSize = 100     
    unlockText.fontColor = SKColor(red: 100.0, green: 100.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    unlockText.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: (self.frame.size.height / 2.8))
    unlockText.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(unlockText)
}
```

[image]
I have added the Fonts Provided by application in the plist so I cm confused :(

Comment: It's the same process as if you were adding a custom font in `UIKit`. Check out this article and make sure you've completed all the steps: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: try with this 'SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "04b 19")' instead of SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "04b_19")

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to add a custom font:

1. Drag and drop the text font into the project. (You have done it)
2. Add in info.plist (You have done it)
3. Check that the source is in the corresponding target. Select the font and in the right menu you have to list the targets, check it
   out.
4. In the project, in the first folder, go to "Build Phases"> Copy Bundles and check that it is added, if not, add it.
5. Verify that the font name is correct.

**To use it** is done like this:

1. You can select it in the storyboard in the viewcontroller.
2. By code:

   `label.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 12.0)`

Then in SpriteKit, are the same steps, but the code it's like this:

```
SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Montserrat Light")
```